# Where does Chromium store bookmarks and browsing history in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, bookmarks, history, chromium

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and Chromium. Where does the latter store bookmarks and history? There are several bookmark folders, but there is no file `~/.config/chromium/` in the system.

Answer (score 1):

In case you installed Chromium via snap, Bookmarks and other settings are stored in the `~/snap/chromium/common/chromium/Default/` directory

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).